# Блогер или блоггер?

Tags: орфография, заимствования, удвоенные-буквы

Как правильно: *бло**гг**ер* или *бло**г**ер*?

**Update:** Учитываем [мнение г-на Артемия Лебедева](http://tema.livejournal.com/872836.html), известного поборника чистоты языка.

Comment: Там, где даёт ссылку на устаревший словарь, - да, ошибается. Но зато он прав в правой части экрана, где даёт ссылку на энциклопедию.

Comment: Яндекс - вообще не аргумент. Он не может не ошибаться, если ошибаются его пользователи. Или вы тоже руководствуетесь принципом "миллион мух не могут ошибаться"?

Comment: Яндекс, не есть авторитет, это просто поисковая машина, которая дает выдачу основываясь на других источниках - в данном случае на словари русского. А вот @behemothus на что ссылается неизвестно, то ли на какую-то кальку, то ли на загадочное укоренение, то ли на упрощение

Comment: Ничего, что я в ваш междусобойчик? 
Shamov, личные разборки удаляю не дожидаясь модератора.
Хватит уже. Говаорите по сути.


По сути. какой мой тезис требует ссылки? 
То, что янедек, как и все поисковики большая помойка? Простите, но это в комментариях не нуждается.

По поводу блоггера - смотрите словарь, хотя бы Лопатина.

Comment: По поводу блоггера - смотрите словарь, хотя бы Лопатина на Грамоте.  
Тезис об общих принципах передачи иноязычных слов основан на анализе фактического материала и мнение (если это можно тут назвать мнением) многих авторитетных лиц. Если действительно нужна ссылка - найду, только чуть позже.

Ссылки же вообще смысл требовать, когда автор **ссылается** на чье-то мнение как на нечто безусловно авторитетное и законченное.

Со своей стороны, могу яЮ наконец, уточнить, что значит "все ваши рассуждения бьются"? Я говорил, у меня нет **рассуждений**, я излагал только факты.

Comment: Подобный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418477/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be/418481#418481

Comment: Еще один подобный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420786/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%85/420789#420789

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Блогер.
Только не потому, что слово "укоренилось" (это и спорно само по себе и в данном случае не играет никакой роли), а потому, что удвоенные согласные в заимствонанных словах последовательно упрощаются (за исключением случаев, когда они и произносятся как удвоенные - и ещё некоторых особо оговариваемых слов).

Comment: Спасибо, что дополнительно разъяснили механизм языкового переноса посредством транскрипции. Мой вариант (пишем, как слышится) был сформулирован слишком сложно. Ваш вариант намного проще и понятней.

Comment: Все же таки не соглашусь. А как же быть с словом *ниггер*? Не получается как то *нигер*... Хотя вроде полностью соответствует ваше

Comment: "Ниггер" - это "калька".

Comment: А *баннер* тоже калька?

Comment: Я говорил, что есть исключения. В "ниггере" и произносится как удвоенное. Сравните с названием страны "Нигер".   

Насчет "кальки" - очередное попадание пальцем в небо.
  
Во-первых, "кальками" называют совсем другие слова, во-вторых, если уж чем-то называть, то не только "ниггер", а вообще все заимствованные слова. Мы же только о них и речь ведем. Ничем ниггер от блогера не отличается. Кроме, разумеется, произношения. Ну и негативной окраски, но это не обсуждается в рамках орфографических вопросов.

Comment: Если имеется в виду тот, кто банит аккаунты, то - калька. А если рекламная растяжка, то это слово давно укоренилось и пишется с одной "н".

Comment: Послушайте, не позорьтесь, посмотрите в словарях, что такое слово-калька. Просить вас сказать своими словами, понимаю, бесполезно. 

*Словообразовательные кальки — это слова, полученные «поморфемным» переводом иностранного слова на русский язык.*
(Вики)

Comment: Я говорил, что есть исключения. В "ниггере" и произносится как удвоенное. Сравните с названием страны "Нигер".   

Насчет "кальки" - очередное попадание пальцем в небо.
  
Во-первых, "кальками" называют совсем другие слова, во-вторых, если уж чем-то называть, то не только "ниггер", а вообще все заимствованные слова. Мы же только о них и речь ведем. Ничем ниггер от блогера не отличается. Кроме, разумеется, произношения. Ну и негативной окраски, но это не обсуждается в рамках орфографических вопросов.

Comment: Ваши комментарии всегда очень ценны. Рассуждения о транскрипции и кальках - не исключение. Пожалуйста, продолжайте...

Comment: Ну и в итоге никто меня так и не убедил в правильности *блогера*, все ваши рассуждения бьются :)

Comment: @Shamov, блогер, ниггер и баннер - конечно, НЕ кальки. Кальками являются, например, имена [Вера Надежда, Любовь](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/204/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) - они выражены русскими словами.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно - "блогер". Причина в том, что слово уже надёжно укоренилось в русском языке, как родное. Т.е. оно не превратилось в "кальку", смысл которой можно объяснить только через ссылку на иностранный оригинал. А в таких случаях, когда заимствованное слово плотненько вошло в язык, при написании руководствуются принципом транскрипции (пишем, как слышится), а не принципом транслитерации (пишем, как пишется в оригинале), который используется при написании "не родных" заимствований.

Comment: А как же быть с Артемием Лебедевым с топ-блоггером? Известна его [сентенция насчет м*даков](http://tema.livejournal.com/872836.html)

Comment: Это банальная провокация.

Comment: Ну не скажу, что банальнальная. Уж коли г-н Shamov так близко к сердцу воспринял...

Бармалей, Артемий Великий может бороться за все, что ему заблагорассудится, включая защиту марсианских диалектов языка пингвинов Антарктики, но авторитетности у него в этой борьбе - меньше чем никакой. Он иногда говорит правильные вещи, но их стоит воспринимать как повод найти аналогичное мненее кого-то более знающего и менее одиозного.

Comment: @DocentI Спасибо. С кальками разобрался. Просто я думал, что калька - это когда нерусское слово записывается русскими буквами (по-научному - транслитерация). Оказалось, что нет.

Answer (score 0):

Из статьи Партаненко Валерии "[Как правильно: блогер или блоггер?](http://fb.ru/article/225983/kak-pravilno-bloger-ili-blogger)":

> В спорах на тему верного написания, как правильно: блогер или блоггер, - самым логичным кажется адресовать вопрос именно филологам. В русском языке эта сдвоенная согласная буква не отвечает правилам, поэтому многие языковеды придерживаются следующей логической цепочки.
>
> Если заимствованным считать только слово «блог», то его создатель должен называться «блогер». Это слово формируется методом добавления к заимствованному слову суффикса «-ер», по аналогу со словом «комбайнер». То есть к заимствованному слову «комбайн» добавляется всего лишь суффикс, что оправдывает отсутствие сдвоенной согласной.

Подобные вопросы на нашем сайте:
[Удвоение согласных при заимствовании из английского](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418477/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be/418481#418481)
[Двойные согласные в заимствованных словах](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420786/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%85/420789#420789)

Answer (score -1):

Рискуя навлечь на себя гнев старейшин, все-таки выскажу крамолу: правильнее таки ***блоггер***, а не *блогер*.

Причин несколько:

1. **Право первой ночи:** русский язык заимствовал готовое английское слово *блоггер*, а вовсе не *блог*, из которого производным вывел *блогер*.
   Изучая недавнюю историю, мы увидим, что *блоггер* явился миру в 2001, а *блогер* — спустя три-четыре года.
2. **Ассоциативная:** в русском языке есть иностранные слова, сохраняющие двойной "**г**", как то: *ниггер, диггер, триггер. **Блоггер*** находится в одном ряду с ними.
3. **Привычная:** надо сказать, самая важная, ибо правила создаются не словарями, а людьми — народом, а словари лишь фиксируют эти правила. В данном случае и Google, и Яндекс единодушно считают, что *блогер* — неправильно, и активно исправляют опечатку на *блоггер*.
   Понятно, что ни тот, ни другой не авторитеты, но они показывают привычки, принятые в среде, — то бишь правила.

Comment: Да нужно это  кому-то - гнев еще изливать. Лучше говорите предметно. 
Бармалей, вы можете привести хоть миллион причин, но скажите на милость, а почему они должны быть значимы?
1. Язык заимствект слово, а не написание. Это еще хорошо, что в слове нет буков, для уоторых отсутсвует точный аналог в кириллице.  
2. Там и произносится удвоенное.   
3. Неактуально. На то и есть словари, чтобы людей править, не наоборот.

Comment: Вы так и не ответили на главный вопрос, вы в слове "блогер" удвоенное Г произносите или нет? В английской-то фонетике нет такого понятия, удвоение там чисто орфографическое, передаёт крвткость предыдущей гласной. Каковой краткости нет уже в русском.

Comment: от того что я произношу слово *что* как *што* я не начинаю писать *што*, поэтому в общем то не играет большой роли как я произношу *блоггер*. Кстати, если на то пошло произношу именно с двумя **г**.

Comment: "Что" как "што" произносите не Вы, а все люди, владеющие орфоэпической нормой русского языка.