# Удвоение согласных при заимствовании из английского

Tags: заимствования, удвоенные-буквы

В английском удвоение согласной, например, в словах `twitter` или `office` носит морфологический смысл. В частности, если б в первом слове его не было, то `twiter` был бы `твайтер` :)

Но в русском они не нужны, у нас и `твитер` и `твиттер` читаются одинаково.

В википедии на эту тему полный бардак, скажем:

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Твиттер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80)

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Офис](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81)

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Отладчик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA) (см. слово дебаггер)

Как в русских текстах лучше всего писать такие слова?

Answer (score 2):

Все слова, указанные в вашем вопросе, уже давным-давно прижились в русском языке, поэтому они были кодифицированы. В словарях уже сплошь и рядом можно найти эти слова. Чтобы их безошибочно писать, рекомендую обращаться к орфографическим словарях (в сети их полно, если что).

А вообще, здесь действительно творится нечто непонятное и об этом уже много говорили. В некоторых случаях пишется двойная согласная, а в других — одна согласная.

Специально для вас оставляю эту ссылку ([перейти](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=57)).

Comment: А что значит "написание слов определяется в словарном порядке" (из ссылки)?

Comment: Если переводить это выражение на простой язык, то это означает, что, если нужно узнать правописание слова, следует заглядывать в словарь.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, Tagirix!

Answer (score 2):

С моей точки зрения, трактовка написания подобных слов от Лопатина лучше всего подходит для русского языка. По этой трактовке, если у корня есть однокоренное слово с одинарной буквой, то удвоения не нужно (*блог-блогер, рэп-рэпер* и т. п.). Это не касается слов, кодифицированных давно (*контроллер, стоппер*). Однако если в русском языке нет корня с одинарной гласной, то пишется удвоенная (*баннер, плоттер, джоббер, джоггинг*).

Comment: "Контролёр" (человек) разве не с одним "л", в отличие от "контроллера" (процессора)?

Comment: Я правильно Вас понял, что это как бы мнемоническое правило, из которого есть несколько исключений?

Comment: @installero - это ползучая реформа орфографии. Словарь ГРамоты.ру ориентируется как раз на Лопатина.