# Двойные согласные в заимствованных словах

Tags: заимствования, удвоенные-буквы

Правильное написание двойных согласных в заимствованных словах - сложная проблема русского письма, можно ли хотя бы в каком-то приближении разобраться в ней или заучивание слов наизусть - это единственно надежное решение?

Как немногословно и понятно объяснить обычным пользователям языка выбор двойных согласных, в частности, **какие факторы  влияли раньше  и влияют сейчас на запись слова,** например: фонетические и графические особенности русского языка, транскрипция и транслитерация, семантика и фонетика двойных согласных в иностранном языке (если такая существует), сохранение традиции написания и т. д.?

Есть ли какой-то общий (главный) принцип при записи слов, **действующий в настоящее время?** Что для нас важнее: точно (и без долгих размышлений) воспроизвести буквенный состав иностранного слова или думать над тем, как лучше вписать его в графическую и фонетическую систему русского языка?

Спасибо.

Comment: Вы говорите об именах собственных или об остальных словах? В первом случае больше ограничений на упрощение в интересах приближения слова к русскому написанию или произношению, при этом общие правила транскрипции свои для каждого языка в паре с русским.

Comment: Хоть бы один пример! Правда, одного мало -- надо бы по крайней мере пяток.

Comment: Я имею  виду обычную лексику. К примеру, почему в слове  коридор пишется одна бука Р,  оно заимств. из нем. яз., где Korridor «коридор» < «проход» < франц. corridor, через итал. посредство восходящего к лат. currere «бежать, идти». Мне всегда хотелось написать там две буквы РР, с трудом удалось заучить слово. А вот аллея пишется с двумя ЛЛ, заимств. в XVIII в. из польск. яз., где aleja "аллея" < франц. allée "проход, дорога", производного от aller "идти".

Comment: Мало затронули такие слова, как круассан, коллектор, фамилии Шемп(п), Дювил(л)яр и другие. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне встретились две точки зрения - Лопатина и Кронгауза; процитирую по чуть-чуть из обоих, но суть я поняла так:

русскому языку претят удвоенные согласные, но в словах, давно укоренившихся в языке, и словарях сохраняется традиционное написание (я - за).

---

***Как правильно писать: шопинг или шоппинг, контролинг или контроллинг, джогинг или джоггинг?***

> По-английски эти слова пишутся с удвоенной согласной, а вот глагол, от
>   которого они образованы только с одной (shop – shopping, jog –
>   jogging). Удвоение в «инговых» формах происходит только для глаголов с
>   кратким гласным звуком в корне, оканчивающихся на письме на
>   одну-единственную согласную букву, то есть букву, обозначающую
>   согласный звук. Это правило связано с особенностями английского
>   произношения и никакого отношения к русскому языку вроде бы не имеет.
>   Кстати, это же правило действует и перед другими суффиксами,
>   начинающимися с гласной буквы, например перед «er» (вспомним dig –
>   digger или актуальное blog – blogger). При заимствовании удвоенные
>   согласные между гласными сохраняются, о чем свидетельствуют, в
>   частности, такие давно привычные слова, как спиннинг или спарринг.
>   Однако не всё так просто, и в старых словарях можно встретить слова
>   фитинг или стопинг (специальные термины), несмотря на то, что в
>   оригинале две согласных – fitting и stopping. А в самых новых словарях
>   появляется слово шопинг, причем именно в таком виде, то есть с одной
>   буквой «п».
>
> Итак, как это ни странно, есть два способа написания подобных слов...

Подробнее см.: [Максим Кронгауз о проблеме «блогер или блоггер?»](http://massimoling.ru/2013/02/21/krongauz-bloger-ili-blogger/)

---

[Ответ справочной службы русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=262066)

> Вот как объясняет Владимир Владимирович Лопатин написание шопинг (а
>   также блогер, блогинг и т. п.).
>
> В новейшей орфографической практике проблема написания удвоенных
>   согласных на конце корня осложнилась особенностями написания некоторых
>   новых заимствований-англицизмов в языке-источнике, для которого
>   характерно удвоение корневого согласного перед суффиксом. Поскольку
>   явление это русскому письму чуждое, следует писать, например,  шопинг,
>   но не шоппинг (ср. прозводящее шоп, также заимствованное из
>   английского), блогер и блогинг (ср. блог), сканер (ср. сканировать),
>   спамер (ср. спам), рэпер (ср. рэп), хотя в английских этимонах этих
>   прозводных перед суффиксами -er и -ing согласная удвоена. Устоявшиеся
>   написания давно заимствованных слов стоппер (спорт.) и контроллер
>   (тех.), к тому же устойчиво произносимые с долгим согласным, не должны
>   препятствовать кодификации  написаний новых подобных заимствований с
>   одиночной согласной перед суффиксом.
>
> Сказанное, однако, не относится к заимствованиям-англицизмам типа
>   баннер, плоттер, джоггинг, киднеппинг и др., у которых в русском языке
>   нет однокоренных соответствий с одиночной согласной.

Comment: Да, проблема слов с суффиксами -er и -ing  наиболее сложна, наверное, эти слова нужно выделить в отдельную группу. Слов много, их количество только увеличивается, ещё много неустоявшихся написаний. Думаю, что здесь можно и нужно навести порядок,  иначе мы потеряем возможность регулировать письмо (будут существовать двойные стандарты, в которых общество просто запутается). Ориентироваться лучше на английский язык: если это удвоение согласных перед суффиксами  -er и -ing  (в англ.языке есть слова с этим корнем, где пишется одна буква), то в русском письме тоже пишем одну букву.

Comment: Наличие таких слов в русском языке  не должно учитываться (они могут появиться потом). Желательно проявить твердость и обязать писаться одинаково всю группу слов (с минимальными исключениями).

Comment: Тогда Вы не лопатинец, а верный и истовый кронгаузец! )))

Comment: Ну да, я за то, чтобы писать  шопинг и блогер, но в этом Лопатин и Кронгауз согласны, но я и за то, чтобы писать банер и джогинг, потому что слова   ban и jog  с определенным значением существуют в английском языке ( это можно проверить, и это не изменится). Так будет обеспечиваться стабильность и обоснованность русского письма.

Comment: Што там банер с джогингом, когда мы с Вами ну совсем не умеем объяснить,  *Надо ли здесь оформлять прямую речь?* 8-( Не, неужто так плохо?! Я сегодня минусов насобирала... Т_Т