# Почему «шипперить» с двумя «п»?

Tags: орфография, заимствования, транслитерация

Почему слово *шипперить*, образованное от англ. сущ. *ship*, пишется с двойным *п*? Я, конечно, понимаю, что если бы мы в английском суффикс *-er* прибавили, то было бы таки *shipper*, но мы же в русском рус. суффикс *-ер* используем всё-таки. Есть какой-то spelling pattern, что ли?

Ещё: представим, что мы от слова *shred*, используя нем. суфф. *-ир*, образовали глагол. Как бы было бы корректно?

> Шредировать.

> Шреддировать.

Comment: Повтор темы https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420786/Двойные-согласные-в-заимствованных-словах  Нам бы что-нибудь новое...

Comment: Так отчего *шипперить* с двумя *п*?

Comment: "Почему слово шипперить, образованное от англ. сущ. ship, пишется с двойным п?"  А это неполная информация. Слова shipping и shipper происходят от слова relationship, что в английском языке обозначает отношения.  Оно образовано от слова relation (отношение, связь, зависимость) с помощью суффикса существительных -ship, который означает состояние человека, связанное с его возрастом, социальными отношениями, иногда деятельностью; или же группу людей,  объединенных этим состоянием.

Comment: Соответственно, трудно понять значение слова в сокращенной записи "шиперить". Индивидуальный подход.  Общая тенденция - это сокращать названия, а вообще в этой теме все довольно сложно.  https://trudy.ruslang.ru/ru/archive/2021-3/132-140   Шрединг напишем без удвоения.